# Phonegap / JQueryMobile App Build Loses Styling

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, cordova

Pulling my hair out!

Running a simple phonegap build, using JQueryMobile pages. The program runs through chrome/firefox etc. but on internet explorer is completely unstyled. IE brings up a warning: blocked content. If I click allow, it runs the javascript and picks up the styling.

Downloading my phonegap build onto an android tablet, and it too doesn't pick up the styling. It looks identical to IE before the blocked content. There has to be something in that surely?

I have tried downloading the JQuery CSS/js files and running them locally on the android but no luck. I have simplified back to one page below. Can anyone help?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="ims">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Main</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#labs" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Labs</a>
            <a href="competency.html" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Equipment</a>  
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <center><p>Copyright</p></center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ims.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Try hosting the javascript files locally instead of referencing them from code.jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missed some jquery files or css or might have incorrectly referenced in your HTML file.
If you have downloaded jquery mobile: js & css; check if it is referenced correctly within 'script' and 'link' tag.

Use document ready function at application start-up.

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/